# overfull hbox toc in KOMAscript

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, overfull

I am trying to fix the overfull that Latex generates to take up the whole page. However, I am also dealing with a similar message for the ToC

[image]
[image]

Now looking at the incriminated ToC I notice that the page numbers are slightly overflowing out of the margin. How can this problem be solved? I understand that the problem occurs because the page numbers are in bold type. I am currently working with the KOMAscript class.

A minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    top = 3cm, 
    bottom = 3cm, 
    right = 3cm, 
    left = 3cm, 
    headsep = 25pt, 
    bindingoffset = 5mm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{MyOne}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyTwo}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{Mythree}
\lipsum[1-250]\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyFour}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyFive}
\lipsum[1-250]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) I can only guess, but not show an answer. I guess, you have to increase the width of the box reserved for the page numbers (either of all entries or the chapter entries). See the `tocbasic` chapter in the KOMA-Script manual for more information.

Comment: @cabohah Ok i edited the question and provide a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already told in a comment, you have to increase the width of the box reserved for the page number. You can do this for the entry of one ToC level only, in your case the `chapter` entries, either using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` or using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    top = 3cm, 
    bottom = 3cm, 
    right = 3cm, 
    left = 3cm, 
    headsep = 25pt, 
    bindingoffset = 5mm
]{geometry}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[pagenumberwidth=2em]{chapter}{chapter}
%\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberwidth=2em]{chapter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{MyOne}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyTwo}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{Mythree}
\lipsum[1-250]\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyFour}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyFive}
\lipsum[1-250]

\end{document}
```

[image: using \DeclareTOCStyleEntry]

See section 15.3 and table 15.2 and figure 15.3 of the [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) manuals for more information about `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` and the features of style `tocline`, and see section 21.8 for more information about `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and how to use it so configure not only the sectioning commands but also the corresponding ToC entries.

If you want to change several entries, you can either use `\RedeclareSectionCommands` (note the `s` at the end) instead of `\RedeclareSectionCommad` or `\DeclareSectionTOCEntries` instead of `\DeclareSectionTOCEntry`.

To change the default for all entries, you can just redefine `\@pnumwidth`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    top = 3cm, 
    bottom = 3cm, 
    right = 3cm, 
    left = 3cm, 
    headsep = 25pt, 
    bindingoffset = 5mm
]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{2em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{MyOne}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyTwo}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{Mythree}
\lipsum[1-250]\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyFour}
\lipsum[1-250]

\chapter{MyFive}
\lipsum[1-250]

\end{document}
```

Note: Additionally it could be a good idea to also change the right indent of the entries. In this case see the ToC entry style feature `rightindent` or the default `\@tocrmarg`.

Comment: @Caborah Wonderful answer I couldn't ask for better. I had already read that section in KOMA documentation but I could not find the part to solve the problem. Again thank you very much